# JAXB: How to add PropertyChangeListener support to classes generated with xjc

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

It seems there was once a plugin JAXB's `xjc` called `inject-listener-code` which added `PropertyChangeListener` functionality to the generated classes (referenced here, for example: http://hwellmann.blogspot.de/2010/05/java-xml-binding-with-property-change.html)

However, according to the [JAXB-RI website](https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Home), this plugin is deprecated and no longer supported. I tried using the listed [Enhanced Property Listener Injection plugin](http://www.no0ne.org/general-purpose/index.html#PropListInjector) but I could not get it working (see below) and I am not sure whether it is compatible with current Java/JAXB versions anyway (and whether it would inject GPL-licensed code into the generated classes which would not be ok).

Is there any other way to add `PropertyChangeListener` support to the generated classes?

I am using Java 8 Update 20.

**Details of trying to run `xjc`:** I tried using JAXB packaged with Java 8 as well as standalone JAXB 2.2.11 and 2.1.13 (since JAXB 2.2.x seems to have dropped `com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.Aspect` which is required by both plugins):

Command-line:

```
xjc foobar.xsd -classpath "xalan-j/xalan.jar;proplistinjector-0.2.2.jar" -Xinject-prop-listeners -no-coll-listeners
```

with JAXB 2.1.13

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationEr   ror: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

After adding extending the classpath with Xalan:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.sun.tools.xjc.model.nav.NType.toType(Lcom/sun/tools/xjc/outline/Outline;Lcom/sun/tools/xjc/outline/Aspect;)Lcom/sun/codemodel/JType;
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractField$1TypeList.add(AbstractField.java:509)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractField$1TypeList.add(AbstractField.java:521)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractField.getType(AbstractField.java:525)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractField.<init>(AbstractField.java:152)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractListField.<init>(AbstractListField.java:118)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.UntypedListField.<init>(UntypedListField.java:118)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.UntypedListFieldRenderer.generate(UntypedListFieldRenderer.java:73)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.DefaultFieldRenderer.generate(DefaultFieldRenderer.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateFieldDecl(BeanGenerator.java:777)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassBody(BeanGenerator.java:558)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:261)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:384)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:221)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:144)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:103)
```

with JAXB 2.2.11:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/outline/Aspect
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractField.<init>(AbstractField.java:152)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.AbstractListField.<init>(AbstractListField.java:118)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.UntypedListField.<init>(UntypedListField.java:118)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.UntypedListFieldRenderer.generate(UntypedListFieldRenderer.java:73)
    at org.no0ne.jaxbworks.proplistinjector.DefaultFieldRenderer.generate(DefaultFieldRenderer.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateFieldDecl(BeanGenerator.java:777)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassBody(BeanGenerator.java:558)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:261)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:384)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:221)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:144)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.Aspect
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Should we maybe resurrect one of the plugins? As a part of JAXB2 Basics: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics

Comment: Sounds good. Some way to listen to updates to the/some elements would be really helpful.

Comment: Ok, could you please check/let me know which of the plugins is more "promising"?

Comment: Can't really tell because I am fairly new to Java Beans and/or JAXB. I am "simply" looking for a way to add code to the JAX-bindings which allows me to listen for changes on some of the nodes (which would allow me to use the JAXB-generated classes as data structures in my program. Otherwise, it would probably just be container for parsing and serializing which I would need to "translate" into a custom data structure in my program, leading to a lot of code duplication and basically render the advantage of `xjc`void).